# Clustering features based on their proximity?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, features, clustering

I have around 500 features (Forests) that I want to cluster based on their proximity, and then work with those clusters. I only have the ID, and shape area of those features.

How can I cluster them?

Comment: may be useful http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p0000000z000000

Comment: It would help if you can post an image illustrating what you want :)

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but are you using that software?  If so, what have you tried?